# Supressing the '^C' string in terminal output when catching interrupts

Tags: linux, go, logging, terminal

I'm intercepting interrupts in my Go program and I'm trying to print out a log message when such thing happens, like that:

`log.Printf("\rCtrl+C pressed in Terminal")`

The problem is, that this way the date part of log.Println is missing. When doing it without the carriage return, like that:

`log.Printf("Ctrl+C pressed in Terminal")`

then the date is being printed out, but it's being prepend by the `^C` string. Is there a way to supress the `^C` string output on the terminal and have the date in the log string at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fmt.Print("\r")
log.Println("Ctrl+C pressed in Terminal")
```

Comment: nitpicking: better use log.Println instead of Printf